# redirect htaccess URL with GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect using .htaccess, from example.com/products/category/subcat/name/?page=0 to example.com/example-subpage

my code not working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/products/category/subcat/name$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=0$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/example-subpage [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably is the handling of the trailing slash in your first condition. You'd need to include it into the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/products/category/subcat/name/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=0$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/example-subpage [R=301,L,QSD]
```

I personally would always prefer a slightly more flexible matching with an *optional* trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/products/category/subcat/name/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=0$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/example-subpage [R=301,L,QSD]
```

That could be simplified to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=0$
RewriteRule ^/?products/category/subcat/name/?$ https://example.com/example-subpage [R=301,L,QSD]
```

And last not least it might make sense to add a bit of flexibility to the remaining condition to also match if other, unexpected arguments get added:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)page=0(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?products/category/subcat/name/?$ https://example.com/example-subpage [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Comment: still not working. Maybe the problem is on the beginning of htaccess file, where all slashes on the end of url are removed: 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]`

Comment: can this code cause problems? `RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]`

Comment: So you have other, additional rules in place? Always post _all_ rules in your question. Please update your question, add the _full_ configuration file and mark that as an "update" to the question. There is an _edit_ button below your question, _use it ..._

Comment: Looks to me like there is another issue. Are you sure that your configuration file is considered _at all_ ? How did you make sure? Do you see any entries in your http server's error log file if you make a test request?